# Why is のに being used here?

Tags: grammar

彼女が大変興奮していたのに気づかなかったのか。
And what if I say
彼女が大変興奮して気づかなかったのか。?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That basically means 'Did (someone) not notice that she was very excited?' The のに here isn't the 'although' のに - it's basic nomalizer の + particle に. I'm not too sure of my guess on the second one, but I think if you said 彼女が大変興奮して気づかなかったのか。it would be 'Was she so excited she didn't notice (something)?'

Comment: How can you tell it's just a nominalizer?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira To be honest, my answer would be 'instinct'. I don't really know how I can tell.

Comment: I deleted my own answer, I believe in your instincts better than mine, but i'm also curious to know, I would've guessed "although" right away

Comment: Felipe, I think the tip-off is "**に**気づかなった". Because the verb takes に, your first guess when you see a に in front of it is that it's taking the preceding noun as an indirect object.

Comment: would this に fall under "主体に働きかけて、ある状態をもたらす物事を表す。" or  "動作・作用の向けられる先を表す。?